# YouTube video in Android app doesn't stop when it's minimized

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, videos, youtube

I got one annoying issue. I encountered it during reading of this question: 
[What is the nationality of Felonious Gru?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37242/what-is-the-nationality-of-felonious-gru-in-despicable-me)

It has YouTube video in the answer. The problem is when I start this video, and navigate to other question\app - the video doesn't stop and still keeps playing in the background. The only solution to stop it is to manually stop the video or close application at all.

Here is a link to my video with steps to reproduce: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbXl4-mFi2U. As you can see on the video:

1. I opened a link from Gmail app
2. Then I started the video playback
3. On 0:05 second, I clicked the Home button, so the application was minimized
4. Then after 6-7 seconds of waiting, I reopened it back from list of last applications
5. As you can see after that video was on 0:13 second, and all that time the sound was playing while application was minimized.
6. Then I reproduced it again by minimizing it on 0:20 and restoring it on 0:27.

Common information:
Nexus 9 and stock Android 5.1. Stack Exchange app v1.0.71 (the latest in the store).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview (just a tip for Kasra when he see this :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Using this answer, [How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview/25380464#25380464), we pause all the web views when the activity pauses, stopping video playback.

Comment: Thanks! i'll mark this answer as answered after test it with 1.0.84